# how to find page number of a website and put it in a variable

Tags: php, pagination, web-crawler

I was stuck at some point. I want your little help. I need to find the navigation pages of a website and put it a for loop. I have done it hard coded but I need it dynamically . 
Here are the examples:

```
<?php 
for ($x = 1; $x <= 5; $x++) {
    $olxcom = file_get_contents('http://olx.com.pk/cars/?page=' . $x . '');
    $file1 = 'olx.txt';
    file_put_contents($file1 , $olxcom, FILE_APPEND);
} 
for ($y = 1; $y <= 5; $y++) {
    $pakwheels = file_get_contents('http://www.pakwheels.com/used-cars/search/-/?page=' . $y . '');
    $file2 = 'pakwheels.txt';
    file_put_contents($file2 , $pakwheels, FILE_APPEND);
} 
for ($z = 1; $z <= 5; $z++) {
    $carmudi = file_get_contents('http://www.carmudi.pk/cars/?page=' . $z . '');
    $file3 = 'carmudi.txt';
    file_put_contents($file3 , $carmudi, FILE_APPEND);
}
?>
```

These number 5 is the page number which I hardcoded. I am trying to find those with a for loop or something else. 
Thanks

Comment: Is there some code that you were trying to format? I'm not sure where some code ends and other code begins.

Comment: Bro I have started three threads like x,y,z that why it's look like this , secondly I want to know how to find the navigation hyperlinks last page so that I will end the loop when the website has last page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to download and parse the html of a page to find the page number. Try [Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) .

```
//random example of selecting from html content
$ret = $html->find('div.foo');
//OR
$ret = $html->find('div[class=foo]');
```

Basically you can access elements, like how you use css selectors. Find the navigation id of the webpage and parse the number of pages from it.

Check `How to find HTML elements? section, tab Advanced` of page.

For example `http://www.carmudi.pk/cars/` contains the total number of pages in

```
<li class="total-pages"> of <strong>1036</strong> </li>
```

You can access it using the class `total-pages` and parsing the text.

If you are looking for a generic solution that works on all websites, as each website has different html for navigation, each requires parsing separately.

Answer (score 1):

Try: than pass to your array;

```
 $dom = new DOMDocument;
 $dom->loadHTML($html);
 foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('a') as $node)
 {
   echo $node->nodeValue.': '.$node->getAttribute("href")."\n";
 }
```

Use an multi demensional array(); http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Example:

```
 <?php

 $my_array = array('x','y','z');
 for ($row = 0; $row < 3; $row++) {
     echo "<p> your stuff item ". $row."<p>";
     for ($col = 0; $col <5; $col++) {
          echo "the inner stuff";
    }
 }

 ?>
```

This should solve your issue...

Comment: Bro thanks for the answer, but I need to find total number of navigation page links like   1,2,3,4,5,6,.......last. I need to find the last number and assign it to the for loop that I have mentioned earlier